# How do I offset the mouse by the window's corner?

Tags: python, pygame, mouse

In a project I am making, a dot follows your mouse within the window. The issue is that the dot is going to the mouse relative to the top left of the monitor, NOT the top left of the window. This makes the cursor way off. Here's what my code looks like.

```
import pygame
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 360))
dot_image = pygame.image.load("dot.png").convert_alpha()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            break
    x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
    y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
    screen.fill([0, 64, 64])
    screen.blit(dot_image, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
```

I have tried subtracting root.winfo_pointery() by the root.winfo_rooty(), or adding by it, but neither does anything. I have searched how to get mouse relative to window, and got this, but it doesn't work for me. It DOES follow the top left of the screen to a tee though!

Comment: why are you mixing `pygame` and `tkinter`? use either one of those, not both. For pygame you can just use `x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()` (and then if you want it to be centered you can use `rect = do_image.get_rect(center=(x, y))` and use the `rect` in the blit method instead of x, y) and for `tkinter` you can use bindings and events which are not really usable in this case that well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not mix different frameworks. In pygame, the current position of the mouse can be determined via [`pygame.mouse.get_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pos). The return value is a tuple that represents the x and y coordinates of the mouse cursor. [`pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.get_pressed) returns a list of Boolean values ​​that represent the state (`True` or `False`) of all mouse buttons.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 360))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

dot_image = pygame.image.load("dot.png").convert_alpha()

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            
    x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.fill([0, 64, 64])
    screen.blit(dot_image, (x, y))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: isn't creating an instance every iteration more expensive than defining it before the loop and then calling the method on the instance? I looked at some examples on how others have used this and they seem to do the same but I don't understand why.

Comment: @Matiiss Thanks. Sorry, my bad. I just copied the code with out reading. That wouldn't even work because `clock()` measures the time to the previous call. The time of the previous call is stored in the object.